# jQuery - DIV to move with scrolling motion and stick position to top and bottom  of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, sticky

There may be already a jQuery plugin which can achieve this, but I can't find one to do exactly what I'm after. If there is, just point me to the tutorial, thanks.

My problem I have is that I have very long page content, and my sidebar is not visible when you are scrolled near the bottom of the page.

So I would like to make my #sidebar div to stick to the top and bottom of my browser window as you scroll up and down the page.

My sidebar height is longer than your typical screen resolution, so I need the bottom of sidebar to sticky to the bottom of the browser window as well as the top of the browser.

So as you begin to scroll down, the side bar will scroll like normal, but when you reach the end the sidebar, it sticks and will not scroll, and as you begin to scroll up, the sidebar will follow until the top of sidebar reaches the browser, then it sticks. Vice Versa.

Is this possible?

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/7ey9g/5/) of simple design layout which is central. I have added a dotted border to the sidebar so you now where the sidebar should stick.

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/7ey9g/5/

Any advice, or you know a online tutorial or demo, would most awesome!

---

**UPDATE**

Please see this attempt by @Darek Rossman

http://jsfiddle.net/dKDJz/4/

He's got the basic idea working. But the scrolling up, causes it to snap to the top. I need the sidebar to be fluid with the scrolling up/down motion. But sticking to the either the top or bottom of the window. It should also not be fixed positioned when the header/footer are in viewport, so it does not overlay.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create a jsfiddle for it, makes it a lot easier to communicate what you're trying to do and come up with an implementation.

Comment: Is this sort of what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/dKDJz/2/

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I'd be happy with the sidebar scrolling until it reaches it's bottom and sticking until the top gets back to the top of the page.

Comment: @steve, nah everyone seemed to think it was too tricky. I will get back to you next week with a file or new fiddle to play. Would be awesome if someone could figure it out.

Comment: Well this is on my personal list of things to demo upstream. If I get the time I'll race you to it...

Comment: This an amazing piece of code, thanks a lot for taking your time to develop one, it will help me alot

Answer (score 4):

I have updated the jsfiddle with my solution.

```js
var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
    $window = $(window),
    sidebartop = $("#sidebar").position().top;

$window.scroll(function() {

    if ($window.height() > $sidebar.height()) {
        $sidebar.removeClass('fixedBtm');
        if($sidebar.offset().top <= $window.scrollTop() && sidebartop <= $window.scrollTop()) {
            $sidebar.addClass('fixedTop');        
        } else {
            $sidebar.removeClass('fixedTop');
        }
    } else {
        $sidebar.removeClass('fixedTop');
        if ($window.height() + $window.scrollTop() > $sidebar.offset().top + $sidebar.height()+20) {
            $sidebar.addClass('fixedBtm');    
        }
                   
        if ($sidebar.offset().top < 0) {
            $sidebar.removeClass('fixedBtm');   
        }
    }
    
});
```

```css
h1, h2 {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#horizon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #cccccc;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

#header, #footer {
    width: 480px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: teal;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden:
}

#content {
    width: 330px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 130px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    border: 2px dashed red;
}

.fixedBtm {
    margin-left: 350px !important;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;   
}

.fixedTop {
    margin-left: 350px !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;   
}

.post {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 320px;
    background: red;
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 175px
}

.buttons li {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 120px;
    background: blue;
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.buttons li:hover {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="horizon">

    <div id="wrapper">
        
        <div id="header">header</div>
        
        <div id="content-wrapper">
        
            <div id="content">
            
                <h1>Latest Posts</h1>
            
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
                <div class="post">This is a post</div>
            
            </div>
        
            <div id="sidebar">
            
                <h2>Sidebar</h2>
            
                <ul class="buttons">
                    <li>Button 1</li>
                    <li>Button 2</li>
                    <li>Button 3</li>
                    <li>Button 4</li>
                    <li>Button 5</li>
                    <li>Button 6</li>
                    <li>Button 7</li>
                    <li>Button 8</li>
                    <li>Button 9</li>
                
                    <li>Button 10</li>
                    <li>Button 11</li>
                    <li>Button 12</li>
                    <li>Button 13</li>
                    <li>Button 14</li>
                    <li>Button 15</li>
                    <li>Button 16</li>
                    <li>Button 17</li>
                    <li>Button 18</li>
                </ul>
        
            </div>
                
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">footer</div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

The sidebar should remain in place at the top when the window is larger than the sidebar and fix to the bottom when the sidebar is larger.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any jQuery or javascript for this. All of this can be achieved in CSS with  `position: fixed`.

Change your sidebar selector to the following

```
#sidebar {
    width: 130px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: right;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    border: 2px dashed red;
    position: fixed;
    right: 35px;
}
```